# How do I save/load back the data after closing the app in multitasking for iPhone?

Tags: ios

I have created an app which requires adding and showing the information added in a table view. However, sometimes we may close the apps in the multitasking.

I would like to know how is it being done whereby after closing the app, we can still continue where we last close the application (or after a reboot).

**CURRENT IMPLEMENTATION:**

EXAMPLE (Added some information in and before closing the app)

- List No. 1
- List No. 2

EXAMPLE: (After closing the app and relaunching it: nothing is displayed)

- -NIL-

**WANTING TO IMPLEMENT:**

EXAMPLE (Added some information in and before closing the app):

- List No. 1
- List No. 2
- List No. 3

EXAMPLE: (After closing the app and relaunching it: displays what was shown before closing the app)

- List No. 1
- List No. 2
- List No. 3

I have been searching around for answers but to no avail. I really hope that I can get some help.

Thanks!

Code for retrieving and displaying the data in the tableview:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"class" forIndexPath:indexPath];

MSDDataController *dc = [MSDDataController sharedInstance];

NSArray  *dataArray = [dc getAllElement];

long row = [indexPath row];

NSString *moduleName = [dataArray[row]moduleName];
[[cell textLabel]setText: moduleName];

NSString *moduleVenue = [dataArray[row]moduleVenue];
[[cell detailTextLabel]setText:moduleVenue];

return cell;
```

Comment: Is this a single screen app so you are only concerned with redisplaying the data or do you need to navigate to the same ViewController as was open before the app was restarted.  It might help if you included example code of how you are currently getting the information displayed in your table.

Comment: @Stuart, I am actually concern with the redisplaying of the data that was last added (or saved).

Comment: OK and how is your MSDataController storing the information that has been added?

Comment: It is storing information as:

`+ (MSDDataController *)sharedInstance;
- (void)addElement:(MSDData *)data;
- (void)removeElement:(MSDData *)data;

- (int)getNumberOfElement;
- (NSArray*)getAllElement;`

Where the MSDData will store the different datas such name, class and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment it sounds like your problem is persisting the data that you have added to the table.  Once the app is closed down the data is gone so you need to store the values some how and then reload them when the app is next opened.  How you persist the data depends on the amount of information you want to store.  If it is very simple relatively small amounts you can use a plist, otherwise you probably want to look at CoreData.

An example of using a plist can be seen here [Save Array to plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678062/save-array-to-plist). Your app is probably more suited to using the more complicated but also more powerful CoreData, you can see loads of tutorials online for example http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started.

Basically before you app is closed you need to call your MSDataController and ask it to write the information to the device and then when the ViewController is loaded again call the MSDataController and get it to load the information back into memory and pass it to the ViewController.

At the moment you are just adding values into an array which is only stored in memory. Once the app is closed and reopened and values in memory will be lost.

Comment: What event/selector/method, if any, is called when the user closes the app in the multi-tasking screen?  Xcode reports `Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9` (i.e. `SIGKILL`, which cannot be trapped).
Is the use of `AppDelegate.applicationWillResignActive`,which is invoked when the user pressed the 'Home' button, the next best option?